# How do I get the numerical solution of this equation?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value

So I have a rather non-trivial differential equation. I can't solve it analytically so I want to solve it numerically using NDSolve. But the thing is that the output just becomes what I had as input, the command does not execute.

So, I have a Lagrangian given by: `L2 = r^3 (((1/Pi)*Sqrt[(1^4)*(Sin[x[r]]^4) + (Pi*(800) - x[r] + (1/2)*Sin[2*x[r]])^2])*(1 + ((1/2)*(x'[r]^2))) + (1/Pi)*(Pi*(800) -  x[r] + (1/2) Sin[2*x[r]]))`

With some help from below (<3) I get:

`eq={D[D[L2, x'[r]], r] == D[L2, x[r]], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}`

Then I use NDSolve to get

`NDSolve[eq, x, {r, 0, Infinity}]`

Where the range of x[r] is from zero to Pi and range of r is from zero to infinity.

But I get some errors:

1: "Power:Infinite expression $\frac{1}{0^3}$ encountered."
2: "Infinity: Indeterminate expression 0.π ComplexInfinity encountered."
3: "NDSolve: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative atr==0."

I know that some people have solved this Lagrangian numerically in a paper so should be possible.

Are there any workarounds I could do to these error messages?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some extra commas in your second expression and your ( and [ don't seem to match up.  I'll see if I  can figure out how to fix but you might be able to fix it faster than I can.

Comment: This works better but complains that it needs more initial conditions:    NDSolve[D[D[L2[x[r], x'[r], r], x'[r]], r] == 
  D[L2[x[r], x'[r], r], x[r]], {x[r], 0, Pi}, {r, 0, Infinity}]

Comment: A second order ODE needs 2 initial conditions for a numerical solution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either:     NDSolve[{D[D[L2[x[r], x'[r], r], x'[r]], r] == 
   D[L2[x[r], x'[r], r], x[r]], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, {x[r], 0, 
  Pi}, {r, 0, Infinity}]

Comment: True, I still don't get it to work with some conditions x[0] == something, x'[0] == something.  The cell just evaluate to "True" and I get an error message saying that there should be an equation in the argument instead of "True"... @DanielHuber

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `x[t]` in the definition of L2 is a typo and should read `x[r]`.

With this assumption, you can simply define L2 as:

```
L2 = r^3 ((V2[x[r], r])*(1 + ((1/2)*(x'[r]^2))) + (1/Pi)*(Pi*(800) - 
       x[r] + (1/2) Sin[2*x[r]]))
```

The equations then read:

```
eq={D[D[L2, x'[r]], r] == D[L2, x[r]], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}
```

Furthermore, the syntax of `NDSolve`is wrong. `{x[r], 0, Pi}` is not needed as `x[r]` is the searched for solution and its range is given by the range of r.

Note further that the equations can not be solved without specifying `V2`.

The command to solve the ODE then reads:

```
NDSolve[eq, x, {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

But to solve it, you need `V2`

Comment: Thanks for this @Daniel Huber, very helpful! 

You are right. That was indeed a typo in the copy-pasting process.

So I did do everything in your answer and substituted V2 explicitly in L2. 

I'm one step closer, but unfortunately, I get into a number of problems. 

1: "Power: infinite expression encountered"
2: "Infinity: Indeterminate expression 0,  Pi ComplexInfinity encountered."
3:" NDSolve: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at r==0."

Are there any workarounds to this problem? May I ask how you knew to put `x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0`?

Comment: I only said you need 2 initial conditions. Their values depend on the problem at hand and is presumably not zero.